# Telerik Nativescript for Blackberry

Tags: blackberry-10, nativescript

We know that Blackberry 10 can run Android app. Does somebody tried Telerik Nativescript for Android and make it run for Blackberry 10?

If so, is it possible to explain the steps to be able to do it? Does Webworks gives any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Telerik NativeScript for Android does indeed work on BlackBerry OS 10 I've tried on (10.3.2.2474). I'll list some tips to get you started, but please keep in mind that NativeScript doesn't officially support BlackBerry OS.

Deployment with the {N} CLI tool (tns) might be problematic - it produces an apk for the app, but it can't deploy it on the device itself, so you need to transfer it somehow and install it on the device.

Alternatively you can use [Telerik AppBuilder](http://www.telerik.com/appbuilder) to build the app (either version will work - VS plugin, CLI tool, Windows or Web clients) and deploy it on the device via QR code scan and install. However, apk installation is a bit slow process on a BB10, so you may choose to use the [NativeScript companion app for development](http://docs.telerik.com/platform/appbuilder/nativescript/running-your-app/run-app). Deployment to the companion app is done via QR codes - it has an integrated QR code reader - and since no installation is necessary, development cycle is faster. There is a small issue with the app - it may seem to crash on the first run, but you can still find the Sync and Scan buttons in the BlackBerry Hub, which you can use to scan the code and start your app.

Releasing the app in the BlackBerry store is out of my scope, but you can check these documents:

https://developer.blackberry.com/android/documentation/rpkg_with_bb_plugin_for_android_stdio.html

https://developer.blackberry.com/android/documentation/publsh_your_app_to_appworld.html

Make sure you've built the app for release as mentioned.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Bundyo for the tips. I fully understand that it is not officially supported by Telerik. I may look stupid, but how do you install .apk file on the phone? From the Amazon store, it is easy, but I have no idea from Google play. It looks like I need an Android phone. I am sure there is a work around, right? Finally, if I use the VS plugin, do I still need to have a subscription plan with them?

Comment: @David there's a Google Play client for BlackBerry10, google for "snap" there's a working Google Play apk for BlackBerry10 on the CrackBerry forums

Comment: Thanks @Alejandro for your help!